# My code is not executing after for loop?

Tags: php

Please check this below code. After for loop remaining code is not executing. It suppose to print "Helo", but it is not printing any thing.

```
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {

      $minrate=$obj_iScripts->min_avg_rate($roomnumber[$id_array[$i]], $amount_ary[$id_array[$i]], $totalrooms);
      $all_min_price[]=$minrate;

      if($_SESSION['star'][$id_array[$i]]>=1 && $_SESSION['star'][$id_array[$i]]<=5)
      {
           //include 'searchresult_table.php';
      }

 }
 echo "Helo";
```

code:

```
public function min_avg_rate($roomnumber,$rates,$totalrooms)
 {
      $ary_name='iArray';
      $total=0;
      for($i=1;$i<=$totalrooms;$i++)
      {
           ${$ary_name.$i}=array();
           $temp=max($rates);
           for($j=0;$j<count($roomnumber);$j++)
           {
                if($roomnumber[$j]==$i)
                {
                     if($temp>$rates[$j])
                     $temp=$rates[$j];
                     ${$ary_name.$i}=$temp;
                }
           }
           $total=$total+${$ary_name.$i};
      }
      return $total/$totalrooms;
 }
```

Comment: Something inside your loop may be triggering an error or performing an `exit`. Have you checked your error log or enabled error reporting?

Comment: what's with `include 'searchresult_table.php';`? Are you including this file inside the loop? if yes please post the code from that file as well? moreover check for `break`, `exit` and `die` statements occurring within your loop

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned off? I'm supposing it's failing somewhere inside the loop.

Comment: yes i have turned off erro_reporting.

Comment: Ok. i got one error after turned on error reporting. Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in D:\xampp\htdocs\chcf\coding\functions\script_functions.php on line 38. But inside for loop that echo "Helo" is working fine

Comment: @Hearaman I'd start by fixing that error. A fatal error produces a total stop in execution

Comment: what @phil said, and maybe post it here if you're still stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what code you have posted -the min_avg_rate() function within your class would seem to be malfunctioning

Comment: To complete the idea in this post: place `echo "enter $i interation";` as first loop operator and `echo "leave$i interation";`, and see, how many iterations are executed.

Comment: It is separate function which i have created that is in script_function.php page

Comment: is there definately 10 items in that array? or should it be a while loop based on the count of items in the array?